# animated scrollTop suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a dead simple jQuery code responsible for navigation through website using animated scrolling.

```
jQuery(".main_menu li a").click(function() {

    var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');

    if(jQuery(this).html() == 'Home') {
        jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: jQuery('body').offset().top }, 1000);
    }
    else {
        jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: jQuery(href).offset().top }, 1000);

    }

    return false;

});
```

After making some unrelated changes in CSS and template the scrolling suddenly stopped working - now I can only scroll to top of the page by clicking "Home". Running the scrolling code in console doesn't work either. I tried to undo the changes I've made but it doesn't seem to help so I'm stuck here looking for the reason of this issue.

[Here](http://interclick2.home.pl/ftp/woda)'s the live version.

Comment: Hovering the links I see you are using anchor tag reference. The return false in your script won't add the hash tag to the url, which you use as your scroll reference. When I do those things I usually add an id to the link e.g. "menu-contact" and then clicking it I will look for an element with the id contact, calculate it's top position and then scroll there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is `All Section id's is getting duplicated`. Section id's woda,oferta, o-firmie, galeria and kontakt.All section id's is getting duplicated double times in HTML markup. Please change  their duplicated id's value for a section then it will working fine.

Comment: You're right but that's really strange. Why is it happening?

Comment: @van_folmert Just inspect the elements myself get 2 section having same id. without context unable guess here.May be copy paste issue.If it is solve your problem could accept as answer.